# What is time complexity of the LTRIM command in Redis?

Tags: redis, linked-list, time-complexity

According to the Redis documentation,`LTRIM` command of Redis has the following time complexity

> Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of elements to be removed
> by the operation.

However, I have some confusion.

For example, If the linked list has 400 numbers from 0 to 399, if I `LTRIM 0 99`, the raw linked node from 99 to 399 has no necessity to be visited I think. Disconnecting the node between node 99 and node 100 is enough maybe.

So I think N is equal to 100 not 300

Please give me a deep explanation.

Comment: I think N is equal to 100 instead of 300 in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the raw linked node from 99 to 399 has no necessity to be visited I think

NO. These nodes need to be released one-by-one, and that's why the time complexity is O(N), where N is the number of elements to be removed.

Comment: Are these nodes released by garbage collector automatically if I do not release them on purpose?

Comment: No. Redis is written in C, which has no garbage collector.

Comment: Although redis does not have garbage collector, but redis use references counting to achieve memory recycling. When object's reference count is zere, the object will be released.

Comment: Redis uses refcounts, true, but only for very specific types of "objects" (i.e. `robj`). List elements aren't refcounted (makes no sense to do so) and thus freeing requires visiting each of the elements (and their macro nodes that are made of skiplists, as the actual implementation is called quicklist - a mix of skip and linked lists).